# HTML/CSS Fitting object/everything on any window size/resolution

Tags: html, css, screen

So, my friend and I are working on a mod for a game called `Minecraft` and I had the duty to make a website where we publish this mod and tell every one what this mod is about.

The problem that I'm currently facing is that I can't get my objects to shrink/grow to fit any browser resolution/window resolution. Currently, I have it so it is formatted to my screen resolution (1920 x 1080) and it seems to be fine, but when I make the window smaller, I have to use the horizontal scrolling bar to get to different areas on the html page.

When I shrink the window, I want it to fit that window.

Same goes with screen monitors. If it isn't my screen resolution, you have to use the horizontal scrolling bar.

How do I make it so my page objects will change size depending on window size/resolution size?

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"</meta>

        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="MOPM-ico/favicon-144.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-config" content="MOPM-ico/browserconfig.xml">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="MOPM-ico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64" href="MOPM-ico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="310x310" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-310.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-196.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-160.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-96.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="64x64" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-64.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-16.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-152.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="MOPM-ico/favicon-57.png">

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

        <title>
            MOPM~
        </title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <!--header-->
            <div class="topHead">
                <img id="headertxt" src="pictures/header.png" width="1919px" height="120px"/>
            </div>

            <!--header buttons-->
                <div class="headButtonSeperator">
                <div class="headButton">home</div>
                <div class="headButton">about</div>
                <div class="headButton">mod info</div>
                <div class="headButton">downloads</div>
                <div class="headButton">videos</div>
                <div class="headButton">links</div>
                <div class="headButton">dev team</div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!--content-->
        <div id="home">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body
{
    background-image: url('pictures/background.png');
}

/*--Classes--*/
.topHead
{
    width: 1919px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #272B30;
    float: middle;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 4px dashed #1EC20B;
}

.headButtonSeperator
{
    width: 980px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 125px;
    left: 509px;
}

.headButton
{
    width: 120px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #313A3D;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0px;

    border-left: 3px solid #282E30;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #282E30;

    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}


.headButton:hover
{
    width: 140px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #313A3D;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    color: #DB481B;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-family: minecraft;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #7A5E55;

    border-left: 3px solid #282E30;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #282E30;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

/*--ID's--*/
#home
{
    display: block;
    width: 918px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 500px;
    float: middle;
    z-index: -1;
}

/*--Fonts--*/
@font-face
{
        font-family: minecraft;
        src: url(fonts/minecraft.ttf);
}

@font-face
{
        font-family: McBold;
        src: url(fonts/ARCADEPI.ttf);
}

@font-face
{
        font-family: McBlock;
        src: url(fonts/Square.ttf);
}


@font-face
{
        font-family: MccBlock;
        src: url(fonts/Squareo.ttf);
}
```

**Edit:**
I am not getting any answers and I really want to get this done so I can work on the other aspects of the page.

Do I need to use percentages?
What am I doing wrong that wont make it position according to resolution/window size?

**Edit:**
So I understand now that I have to make my page responsive by not using `px`
How exactly do I make it responsive and what measurements can I use?

Edit:
<strike>I did a little bit of testing with percentages and it didn't seem to work.
In this picture, i am testing the head banners width with a width: 100%
I made the window smaller and the top wording (which is an image) doesn't
shrink down to the size of the window.</strike>

http://prntscr.com/47v2ub <---image

**Edit:**
Update on the above edit:
I figured out that i had to make >.topHead also have a >width: 100

The problem i am facing now is that if the browser gets too small, all of my buttons bunch up

Comment: You should look into 'responsive design'. A google search should turn up plenty of templates for you to follow. I would suggest bootstrap.

Comment: but i am not getting a direct answer on how to do this though. it just talks all about what it is. What do i have to do to keep every thing positioned the way it is and look the same on different resolutions

Comment: do i have to add percentages? if so, how do i convert px to percent.

Comment: The Bootstrap Framework is an entirely different style of designing web pages than what you have shown. Yes, you can use percentages, for instance `width: 50%;`, but why do that when somebody has already written all of the classes for you in Bootstrap.

Comment: but i dont know bootstrap :/ i guess that is another problem :P

honestly, ive heard about bootstrap but i never actually knew what it was.

Even though using bootstrap might be the easiest way, how can i do it w/o bootstrap if possible

Comment: btw i dont want a template that was already made. I want to make my own page the way i want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a page responsive you need to keep two things in mind:

1. Don't use fixed quantities for `width` and other dimensions on your page (like `px`).
2. If you do, control things with `Media Queries` which let you change the styles on your page according to the changes in the screen size.

[See More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: yes, but...
how exactly to i make it responsive?
what measurements can i use and such?
How can i achieve responsive-ness?

Comment: Use percentages, and adjust things with `Media Queries`

Comment: ok thanks! percentages have worked so far but i dont really know how it will work with every thing else...

ill do some testing

Comment: Open your website in Chrome and resize your web developer tools to get different sizes of screen, it even shows the dimensions of the page while you resize it. That will help you grealty in testing your page

Comment: You have to experiment and learn, that's the best way to do it. You won't get a straight way answer for such a quest, all anyone can offer is some guidance.

Comment: Well thanks :) so far it is working good!! I have ran into another problem though.

say i'm changing the dimensions horizontally. My buttons do this http://prntscr.com/47vrb1

If the browser gets too small horizontally, i want it to do something like this http://prntscr.com/47vrxs.    how is that achievable?

Comment: Just a rough example for what you wish to do: http://jsfiddle.net/tfKamran/p4wXz/2/

Comment: If your question is answered, you may accept my answer.